# Why can't I run Coffeescript project in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, coffeescript

[Newbie]  I downloaded Netbeans 7.3 RC2 and installed it and also the CoffeeScript plugin.  Then I created a new CoffeeScript project which gave me two files - HelloWorld.coffee and Cakefile.  I try to run the project but the Run Main Project command under the Run menu is dim indicating that I can't select it.  How do I run this program?  (I'm brand new to this; I haven't tried any other versions of NetBeans or Coffeescript.)

Answer (score 0):

the netbeans-coffeescript-plugin is used to have syntax-highlighting for cofeescriptfiles in the netbeans ide. you still need a third party tool to compile your coffeescripts into javascript in order to run them. you can use the guard gem in ruby for example